# Highcharts - Display the noData overlay and the x-axis labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I can get the [noData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#noData) overlay working when there are no series data values, and I can get the x-axis displaying along with the noData label by setting a [xAxis.max](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.max) value, but I can't get the x-axis labels displaying.

Any ideas?

Ideally I would be able to do this without any fake series data (as without data I don't have any series names to provide). This is used in a column chart of well defined x values (like in the js fiddle below, with known fruits, where only each series counts are dynamic)

Closest I've been able to get is this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eLdn6Lfc/

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container1',
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Mulligatawny', 'Crab bisque', 'Lima bean', 'Wild mushroom'],
            max:3
        },
        series: [{
            data: []
        }],
        lang: {
            noData: "No Soup For You!"
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to set min limit to x-axis if there is no data.

Working solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ese7sdr1/10/)

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'column'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Mulligatawny', 'Crab bisque', 'Lima bean', 'Wild mushroom'],
    min: 0,
    max: 3
  },
  series: [{
    showInLegend: false,
    data: []
  }],
  lang: {
    noData: "No Soup For You!"
  },
});
```

Comment: That doesn't display the `noData` overlay. See the top chart in my question's linked js fiddle.

Comment: @Tyson - add (in your fiddle) `min: 0` for your first chart. This works. (http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/eLdn6Lfc/1/).

Comment: @wergeld Sorry on my phone, only quickly looked at the jsfiddle. Thanks, both of you! But still only 2/3 working. Still displays 'Series 1' which is annoying. Any way around that?

Comment: @Tyson - you can add `showInLegend: false` on that dummy series you added. Or you can update the series' properties on `chart.events.load` to hide from legend. (http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/eLdn6Lfc/2/)

Comment: @wergeld Ahh, `showInLegend`, perfect, thanks. I was dynamically changing `legend.enabled` depending on if there was series data or not and it felt gross. New to highcharts but very impressed so far!

Comment: Dharmendra, if you could update your answer to the full solution as discussed above I'll accept this.

Comment: Just added complete solution :-)